# IBM watson for sentiment analysis crashing on import

Tags: python, python-2.7, ibm-watson, sentiment-analysis

I'm trying to use IBM watson for sentiment analysis. but it is crashing on the import: `from ibm_watson import NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1`

The whole code snippet is

```
import json 
import constants from ibm_watson import NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1 from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators
import IAMAuthenticator from ibm_watson.natural_language_understanding_v1 import Features, SentimentOptions

class SentimentAnalysis:

    def __init__(self):
        authenticator = IAMAuthenticator(constants.IBM_WATSON_KEY)
        this.natural_language_understanding = NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1(
            version='2020-08-01',
            authenticator=authenticator
        )
        this.natural_language_understanding.set_service_url(constants.IBM_WATSON_URL)

    def analyse_sentiments(self, data):
        response = this.natural_language_understanding.analyze(
            text=data,
            features=Features(sentiment=SentimentOptions())).get_result()
        assert isinstance(response, object)
        return response
```

My python version is Python 2.7.16
Installed IBM watson using **pip install --upgrade "ibm-watson>=4.6.0"**

The error I'm seeing is

```
/usr/bin/python /Users/rabbal1892/Desktop/DeepInsight/nextcontent-etl/scrapers/sentiment_analysis.py Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/rabbal1892/Desktop/DeepInsight/nextcontent-etl/scrapers/sentiment_analysis.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ibm_watson import NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1   File "/Users/rabbal1892/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/ibm_watson/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from ibm_cloud_sdk_core import IAMTokenManager, DetailedResponse, BaseService, ApiException   File "/Users/rabbal1892/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/ibm_cloud_sdk_core/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from .base_service import BaseService   File "/Users/rabbal1892/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/ibm_cloud_sdk_core/base_service.py", line 68
    service_url: str = None,
               ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'll appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you should use the word exploding. Do you mean crashing?

Comment: Yeah, it is crashing. I have updated the question to include the error I'm seeing.

Answer (score 0):

The [ibm-watson project description page](https://pypi.org/project/ibm-watson/#python-version) mentions it's only tested on Python V3.x versions.

There is a lot of Python v3 syntax that is not compatible with Python v2.

Since you mention you have Python v2, you should Python v3 instead if you want to using the ibm-watson library as is, you will have to **use Python v3**.